# problem in my network config in ubuntu

Tags: 22.04

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTlVV.png)I have an ubuntu 22.04 VM machine and it's related to the bridged interface of my host it's means I get an IP @ from my DHCP of my LAN and now I change the network config to a static config I configure a static IP to my ubuntu but when I try to see the config with "IP a" cmd I don't find the config like the screenshot below
this is my static config:

## This is the network config written by 'subiquity'

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens32:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.43.19/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.43.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.43.1, 8.8.8.8]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7ah2.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkHov.png)

Comment: Netplan says ens32 but `ip a` says ens33. Please fix. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: thanks bro i fixed it